# Creating ELB in CloudFormation - Stickiness Policy is Ignored?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, elastic-load-balancer

I want to create an ELB as part of a CloudFormation stack that has Load Balancer stickiness that doesn't expire (e.g. a CookieExpirationPeriod property that I don't specify). Below is the relevant ELB portion of the template (YAML format).

```
HAELB:
Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
Properties:
  CrossZone: 'true'
  HealthCheck:
    HealthyThreshold: '5'
    Interval: '10'
    Timeout: '5'
    Target: HTTPS:8443/health
    UnhealthyThreshold: '2'
  Instances:
  - Ref: Instance1
  - Ref: Instance2
  - Ref: Instance3
  LBCookieStickinessPolicy:
  - PolicyName: HASessionStickiness
  Listeners:
  - InstancePort: '8443'
    InstanceProtocol: HTTPS
    LoadBalancerPort: '443'
    Protocol: HTTPS
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:iam::xxx
  LoadBalancerName: prodtest
  SecurityGroups:
  - sg-xxx
  Scheme: internet-facing
  Subnets:
  - subnet-xxx
  Tags:
  - 
    Key: Name
    Value: prodtest
```

(I redacted some info with xxx)

The template and ELB get created without issue, but when I check the stickiness on the console, it says it is disabled. Am I misconfiguring the LBCookieStickinessPolicy? As I mentioned, I want it to be enabled but have no expiry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you've defined the stickiness policy with the load balancer, but you have not associated the stickiness policy with a listener.

Add the `PolicyNames` property to your listener to associate your policy with a listener:

```
LBCookieStickinessPolicy:
  - PolicyName: HASessionStickiness
Listeners:
  - InstancePort: '8443'
    InstanceProtocol: HTTPS
    LoadBalancerPort: '443'
    Protocol: HTTPS
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:iam::xxx
    PolicyNames:
      - HASessionStickiness
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed this! Thank you for the quick and concise answer - works!